# How can I make grub visible while starting computer?

Tags: dual-boot, grub

I have installed Windows 10 and Linux Mint on two separated physical SSD
Grub isn't visible while starting; I am able to load windows or Gnu/Linux by manually changing the load priority in BIOS. I have tried to change windows settings. Specially I unchecked "Turn On fast startup" option in

```
Control Panel -> System and Security -> Power Options -> Chose what the power buttons do
```

I've reinstalled grub from Gnu/Linux using command:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda1
```

Also I've tried to change **GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT** in  `/etc/default/grub`and updated, using command `update-grub`

UEFI mode disabled in BIOS.

Please tell me what can I do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is a direct result of UEFI and your installation choices: you decided to install grub and Mint on `/deb/sdb` and the Windows boot manager on `/dev/sda` *and it works!*.

You *could* install grub on `/dev/sda` as well and then it will show Windows and Mint, **but I would not do that** as major updates to W10 sometimes break `grub` and then you have to do a [`boot-repair`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Don't do anything because you have the best of both worlds now, and it's now much harder for W10 to mess up Mint and for Mint to mess up W10.

---

If you insist on having Grub as your boot loader,

1. **Make a full system backup using [CloneZilla Live](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php)**
2. Take a data backup using W10 and Mint utilities just in case (*1 copy does not make a Backup and all that*)
3. Run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and see if that solves the problem automatically for you.
4. Review your install and ensure Mint is installed in UEFI mode
5. [Manually install grub on `/dev/sdb`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001311/how-to-manually-install-grub-with-two-hard-disks)
6. Reboot

Comment: I think there is a way to tell grub about additional OSs (including those on different devices).

Comment: I think the OP doesn't have a bootloader, they're not seeing the EFI boot menu: they say they need to change the boot priority in the BIOS. And grub is installed on `/dev/sda1`, not sdb. That's probably the issue.

Comment: i've followed by second answer with boot-repair and it works for me, thanks!